# Flex: Set bytearray to image component

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I am trying build an image editing component to add caption to uploaded images.
In this application first user uploads multiple images from desktop. User selects one of the image to add text to it.
**ImageWithText Component**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         height="600"
         width="800"
         creationComplete="init()"
         >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            private var _sourceByteArray:ByteArray;
            public function source(value:ByteArray):void
            {
                _sourceByteArray = value;
            }   

            protected function init():void
            {
                if(_sourceByteArray == null)
                    return;

                centerImage();
            }
            protected function centerImage():void
            {
                imageMeme.x = width/2 - imageMeme.width/2;
                imageMeme.y = height/2 - imageMeme.height/2
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>
    <mx:Image id="imageMeme" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0"/>

</s:TitleWindow>
```

**Parent App:**

```
private function showTextControls(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if(listOfSelectedImages.length == 0)
                {
                    Alert.show("Please select an image to edit.");
                    return;
                }
                var byteArrayCropImage:ByteArray  = getPreviewImageByteArray();
                imageWithText.source(byteArrayCropImage);
                imageWithText.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, handleCreationComplete);

                PopUpManager.addPopUp(imageWithText,this, true);
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(imageWithText);
}
```

It opens up a blank Title window with just text on it. No image gets loaded in title window.

Comment: Try putting `trace()` statements in `source()`, `init()`, and `centerImage()`.  I note from your code that you're never passing the `ByteArray` to the `Image` component; first you need to make sure that the `Image` has something to display.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't hunted down the particular issue with the current approach, but the way I would do it would be to set up the `ByteArray` as a bindable variable, then link the `Image`'s source to the `ByteArray` in the MXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         height="600"
         width="800"
         creationComplete="init()"
         >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            [Bindable] // change 1/3
            private var _sourceByteArray:ByteArray;
            public function source(value:ByteArray):void
            {
                _sourceByteArray = value;
            }   

            protected function init():void
            {
                if(_sourceByteArray == null)
                    return;

                imageMeme.filters = new Array();
                // imageMeme.load(_sourceByteArray); // change 2/3
                centerImage();
            }
            protected function centerImage():void
            {
                imageMeme.x = width/2 - imageMeme.width/2;
                imageMeme.y = height/2 - imageMeme.height/2
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>
    <mx:Image id="imageMeme" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0"
            source="{_sourceByteArray}"/> // change 3/3
    <mx:HBox id="box_Label">
        <s:Label id="labelOfImage" text="Blah Blah Blah"/>  
    </mx:HBox>

</s:TitleWindow>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It did not work for me though.

Comment: Does it work if you also comment out the line that says `imageMeme.filters = new Array();`?

Comment: Also I wonder if the `HBox` might be concealing the image?  Just a couple of ideas.

Comment: Updated the code as per your suggestion but still no luck. :(

Answer (score 0):

creationComplete fires once, are you sure it doesn't fire prior to passing the source?